# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been asked to write a simulator, the end goal being to see how much ink ends up on a cylinder at the end of a chain of maybe 15 or so rollers. I'm currently trying to set-up a dictionary which defines the rollers. From this i wanted to write a function which will take user input, 'roller_diameter', find the ratio of the given diameter to a fixed diameter and convert this into an integer number of 'segments'. I'm not a programmer (i'm learning Python[2.7] using internet resources) and am struggling with the TypeError: can't multipy sequence by non-int type 'float'
I'm sure this is a trivial issue and I have looked at the related answers but have been unable to understand what specifically I'm doing wrong...Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, here's the code (with only a few 'rollers'), please don't laugh...

```
Rubber = True  
Copper = False  
CW = 1  
ACW = -1  
num_rollers = 4  
plate_diameter = 406.4  

rollers = [{} for i in range(num_rollers)]  
rollers[0] = {'top_seg': 0, 'roller_diameter': [], 'segments': [], 'material': Copper, 'direction': ACW, 'ink': []}  
rollers[1] = {'top_seg': 0, 'roller_diameter': [], 'segments': [], 'material': Rubber, 'direction': CW, 'ink': []}  
rollers[2] = {'top_seg': 0, 'roller_diameter': [], 'segments': [], 'material': Copper, 'direction': ACW, 'ink': []}  
rollers[3] = ['top_seg': 0, 'roller_diameter': [], 'segments': [], 'material': Rubber, 'direction': CW, 'ink': []}  

R = rollers[i]  

def roller_data():  
    global roller_diameter  
    roller_diameter = float(raw_input("Enter the roller diameter" + str(i) + ': '))

for i in range(num_rollers):  
    roller_data()  
R['segments'] = int(round(rollers[3]['segments']*roller_diameter/plate_diameter))  
R['angle'] = (360.0/R['segments'])  

print rollers[3]['segments']
```

The TraceBack is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\\datasvr\users\rioliver\Python2.7\dict_test_v2.py", line 24, in <module>
R['segments'] = int(round(rollers[3]['segments']*roller_diameter/plate_diameter))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

When you run this code it doesn't matter what you enter for diameter (I have been using 85, 95, 110, 120) but it makes no difference what numbers are used. I would like it to take any number (integer or floating point) and round any floating points.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the traceback, something's wrong. In your code, you don't round to `int`, in the traceback you do.

Comment: apologies, that was an error on my part! the line which gives that error should read: R['segments'] = int(round(rollers[3]['segments']*roller_diameter/plate_diameter))

Comment: Use the [edit] link to edit the code. Below you are trying to post code in comments, it's bound to fail. You can add all the necessary info to your question.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help, I hadn't realised I could edit the original...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
R['segments'] = int(round(rollers[3]['segments']*roller_diameter/plate_diameter))
```

You take `rollers[3]['segments']`, multiply it by `roller_diameter`, and then divide by `plate_diameter`.  This gives you the error message

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

This tells me that you're trying to multiply a sequence -- say, a list or a tuple -- by a float.   And if I understand correctly, `rollers[3]['segments']` is still an empty list, and you're trying to multiply it by `roller_diameter`, which is a float.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, because you never assign anything to the `segments` key, as near as I can tell.

Some other notes:

```
rollers[3] = ['top_seg': 0, 'roller_diameter': [], 'segments': [], 'material': Rubber, 'direction': CW, 'ink': []}
```

This line gives a SyntaxError, so obviously it's not the code you ran.  Please always copy and paste the code you actually ran into the box, otherwise people have to distinguish between "the bugs in the OP's code" and "the bugs in how the OP edited the code on StackOverflow".

```
R = rollers[i]
```

I think you think this means that `R` will now always point to the `i`-th element in `rollers`, but that's not how Python works.  What it means is "tell the name `R` that it now refers to whatever object `rollers[i]` currently describes".  `i` is 3 at this point (a leftover from the list comprehension you used), so `R = rollers[3]`.  If you change `for i in range(num_rollers)` to `for j in..`, you'll get

```
    R = rollers[i]  
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

because it's trying to get the value of `i` at that moment, and there *is* no `i`.

```
def roller_data():  
    global roller_diameter  
    print i
    roller_diameter = float(raw_input("Enter the roller diameter" + str(i) + ': '))
```

You don't need a global variable here.  If you want to make the input a function, just return a value:

```
def read_diameter(i):
    return float(raw_input("Enter the roller diameter # {}: ".format(i)))
```

and then assign it somewhere when you get it back, like

```
rollers[i]['roller_diameter'] = read_diameter(i)
```

and use *that* value in the calculation, not the global `roller_diameter`.

I think there's an indentation error in your last few lines and you wanted the `R['segments']` bit to be indented -- but then you hardcode `rollers[3]` rather than use `rollers[i]`, so maybe I'm wrong -- but remember that your `R` is always `rollers[3]`.  Either use `rollers[i]` in the loop or set `R = rollers[i]` *inside the loop* so that that line is getting a new value of `i` each time it executes.

Comment: Thanks DSM! Thanks for breaking it down for me, I'll be trying your suggestions this afternoon, your explanation makes sense, thanks for taking the time to comment on my terrible code!As for the other stuff, i'm pretty new to forums in general and obviously didn't figure out the complexities of posting here before i went ahead and did it anyway! In future I'll certainly try and be clearer, i think i messed it up because it took me almost an hour to figure out how to post code, in which time i'd made a few amendments and tested, hence the anomalies...Thanks again though, it's much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The Error output is showing

```
R['segments'] = int(round(rollers[i]['segments']*roller_diameter/plate_diameter))
```

where as in your code you have 
    R['segments'] = float(round(rollers[3]['segments']*roller_diameter/plate_diameter))

Are you, perhaps, running the correct or the most up to date version of your code? Is the code chunk you have here the same as the  code that you are getting this error from?

Regards

Comment: sorry, I was having trouble getting stack overflow to recognise my code as code! so i re-typed it and obviously made an error, apologies for the confusion! it should be 3 in those brackets, the error was from a test i'd ran as i was trying to post the question.... Thanks for looking!

Comment: Post the code from the test you run which gave you this error so I can try and run it from my end to replicate the error message and see how I can help you. 

*To get SO to recognise your code as code you need to indent each line of the text with four spaces (or more).

Comment: i can't seem to repost the code. the code i was testing was exactly the same as that posted in the initial comment except the line:     R['segments'] = float(round(rollers[3]['segments']*roller_diameter/plate_diameter))

Comment: this comment system is pretty annoying, i keep posting incomplete comments! basically, the code i ran was exactly the same except i replaced the [i] in the initial code with [3] in the line quoted above (line 21 in my Notepad++)...i hope this helps

Comment: another apology - i've just realised i'd changed the int to float. the line in question should read: R['segments'] = int(round(rollers[3]['segments']*roller_diameter/plate_diameter))